# apply a function to each element in a colmun of a table in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

A table saved in a postgres database is composed of multiple columns.
I want to apply an already saved function "to_seconds(t text)" on each element of a specific column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there anything stopping you from just applying your user defined function to each column, i.e.

```
SELECT to_seconds(col1) AS col1_udf,
       to_second(col2)  AS col2_udf,
       ...
FROM yourTable
```